# Request object response always empty

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Here's my main.js

```
require('sdk/request').Request({
    url:'https://google.com'
    ,onComplete:function(response){
        console.log('response',response)
    }
}).get()
```

which gives me

```
console.log: extension: response constructor {}
```

At first I thought it was a permissions thing, but I whitelisted google and still no response

```
"permissions": {
    "private-browsing": true
     ,"cross-domain-content":["https://google.com"]
}
```

I'm using FF31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the object wasn't actually empty, it just appeared empty in the console. When I `console.log(response.text)` I get the results I expect. This is probably b/c `text`,`json`, etc are prototypes of the object and the console ignores prototypes.

Comment: This is due to console.log of objects being live: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=754861

Comment: Does that mean `JSON.stringify` would not have revealed human-readable content inside the object?

Comment: JSON.stringify should work as you would expect. One trick I do when working with addons is, I open the browser console and type my addon's name into the filter field - only log messages from my addon will show up there.